# Reading properties in the backstage view

Tags: office-js

Is is possible to read the properties from the backstage view. For example can the API read the location of the Autorecover file location?

Comment: What Office application are you working on? Word has a [DocumentProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/word/word.documentproperties) class, although I don't think it includes the autosave location.

Comment: I am referring to Excel but Word would be helpful as well

Comment: There's a [Excel DocumentProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.documentproperties?view=excel-js-preview) too; but it doesn't include the autosave location.